# Do I want a new MAC address if my VirtualBox clones will never run at the same time?

Tags: virtual-machine, state, virtualbox, mac-address

I work as a tech seller of a server side container-based app.

- I run the app on an Ubuntu VM and then access it through the browser on a different machine in the same network.
- I need multiple versions and multiple data setups.

So I have created a base VM with ubuntu, a set of clones with a give version of the app, and muliple clones of each with different data setups.

- The VMs are on a different machine, so I use bridged mode.
- I only run one clone at a time, so I always get the same IP.

Here are my questions:

- Should I create a new set of MAC addresses for each clone or leave them the same?
- Will this ever affect the IP the VM is leased?
- Will this ever effect the session state when I access the app from my laptop?

  - Meaning: if I close down one VM and start up another, is there something I should clear out in my browser, before logging on again to ensure correct state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to reuse MACs on the same network.

The reason is that network switches will remember the MAC address and will direct traffic to the target port even when machine/VM is powered off. Usually, a switch will forget the MAC after a while if it is not reachable, but this time can depend on arbitrary settings from switch manfacturer or network administrator.

So with tha same MAC you can be lucky or not, but even if it appears to work it will still be non-deterministic and can break at any time.

Comment: Ok, so I should `always` change the MAC addresses: understood. For clarity: you're saying that the problems can manifest as a saved state on my router rather than a saved state from my web browser?

Comment: On the *switch* to be precise. As for the browser, it will not know anything about changes to the network, but it will probably try to use invalid HTTP sessions (from old VM). In this case, clearing cookies and cache should fix it.